# Change the name of the directory file for sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to simplify everytimes I want to enter into my SQL in the terminal by using a different name for my directory file. Also, I am on macOS.

This is my directory file:

**/usr/local/mysql-8.0.12/bin/mysql -u root -p**

Can I have something like this? :

**/usr/local/sqlmm/bin/mysql -u root -p**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (works like  an alias) from your desired name to the current install:

```
ln -s /usr/local/mysql-8.0.12 /usr/local/sqlmm
```

When you upgrade, delete it (using `rm`) and create a new one to the new install, so your standardised path remains constant.

Comment: It said permission denied